# Issues running java in Solaris 9 container

Tags: java, solaris, zones

I have a solaris 9 container built from a physical server using flarcreate. Everything seems fine, except when trying to trying to run any "java -server" process it fails with the following error

This is on a Sunfire T1000 machine running **Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC**
 Running jdk1.5.0_15

> Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   requested -4 bytes for size_t in
>   /BUILD_AREA/jdk1.5.0_15/hotspot/src/os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp.
>   Out of swap space?

As far as I can tell I'm not actually out of swap space.

Running java in client mode works without a problem.

Googles only suggestion is related to x86.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I find re-deploying java solves such errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the update level being different from the initial system that the Solaris system was creatd on the patch level support on the solaris 10 system that you are hosting the containers on. This was fixed in a patch from Sun, but you need a support contract to get it. I've burned a few hours into getting this issue fixed, but don't have a solution without a support contract.

Let me know how if works for you.